# Apache Solr Http Transport Exception

Tags: apache, exception, transport

I've implemented Solr on an Ubuntu 14.04 server and it works - I can login, see the dashboard, the core, no errors, etc…

Now I'm trying to install/config "Open Semantic Search" - looks like a promising tool! - and when try to hit the main page I get this error:

```
Error:

exception 'Apache_Solr_HttpTransportException' with message ''404' Status: Not Found' in /var/www/html/search/Apache/Solr/Service.php:338 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/search/Apache/Solr/Service.php(1170): Apache_Solr_Service->_sendRawGet('http://localhos...') #1 /var/www/html/search/index.php(749): Apache_Solr_Service->search('*:*', 0, 10, Array) #2 {main}
```

I've messed about with the "Open Semantic Search" config file, changed localhost to the ip, tried different paths, looked through the service.php and index.php, used the domain vs. localhost - I'm just at a loss. I think it's a path issue - maybe permissions?

If anyone has a solution - great! But if someone could just explain that error to me like I was born in the 60's ;) that would be awesome.

Comment: I was born in 1958 and I resent that remark.